# Prove $\frac{\Gamma(t+a)}{\Gamma(t)} = t^a(1+O(1/t)$ using Stirling's formula

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function, ratio

Let $t$ be positive integers and $a$ is fixed. Stirlings' formula for the Gamma function yields
$$
e^{-t}t^{t+\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi} \leq \Gamma(t+1) \leq e^{-t}t^{t+\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}e^{\frac{1}{12t}}.
$$
Because $\Gamma(t+1) = t\Gamma(t)$, I have
$$
e^{-t}t^{t-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi} \leq \Gamma(t) \leq e^{-t}t^{t-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}e^{\frac{1}{12t}}.
$$
Now,
\begin{align*}
    \Gamma(t+a) &= t(t+1)\dotsc(t+a-1)\Gamma(t) \\
    &= \frac{t(t+1)\dotsc(t+a-1)(t+a)\Gamma(t)}{t+a} = \frac{\Gamma(t+a+1)}{t+a}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\Gamma(t+a)}{\Gamma(t)} = \frac{\Gamma(t+a+1)}{\Gamma(t)(t+a)}.
$$
By using Stirling's formula
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\Gamma(t+a)}{\Gamma(t)} &= \frac{\Gamma(t+a+1)}{\Gamma(t)(t+a)}\\
    &\leq e^{-t-a}(t+a)^{t + a +\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}e^{\frac{1}{12(t+a)}}e^{t}t^{-t + \frac{1}{2}}(2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{t+a}\\
    &= e^{-a}e^{\frac{1}{12(t+a)}}(t+a)^{t + a -\frac{1}{2}}t^{-t + \frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}

Now I'm not sure how to evaluate this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to take logarithms
$$A=\frac{\Gamma(t+a)}{\Gamma(t)}\implies \log(A)=\log (\Gamma (t+a))-\log (\Gamma (t))$$ Now, for large $x$
$$\log (\Gamma (x))=x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} (\log (2 \pi )-\log (x))+\frac{1}{12
   x}-\frac{1}{360 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$ Use it twice and continue with Taylor expansion
$$\log(A)=a \log (t)+\frac{a^2-a}{2 t}-\frac{2 a^3-3 a^2+a}{12
   t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)$$ Back to Taylor
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=t^a \left(1+\frac{(a-1) a}{2 t}+\frac{(a-2) (a-1) a (3 a-1)}{24
   t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)\right)$$ Truncate wherever you wish.

Comment: Sure, it looks indeed easy with this method! But I should be able to use Stirling's formula to prove the statement too, right?